# Can Azure Application Gateway distribute request to specific URL?

Tags: azure

I have a use case where my cluster has 3 VMs working as head node in HPC Pack and a bunch of other VMs working as compute nodes.

So basically, after creating this cluster, i must install a special HCP client, from this client, i type the DNS name of each of VMs to access the HPC management interface.
For example: https://head-node-1.azure.com

Of course, if i access this DNS from Chrome, i only see IIS page.

I wants to create a load balancer with its DNS name. Let's say https://load-balancer.azure.com

So from my client, every time i access load balancer DNS name, i can see the management interface, not IIS page.

How can i do that?

Comment: Is there any update on your side?

Comment: Hi Nancy, i figured out the problem. Adding another certificate on backend side is needed. 
To put it simply, 
1 cert on front-end
1cert on back-end because HPC used cert to authenticate between nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding you correctly. Basically, Azure Application Gateway supports [URL path-based routing rules.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal)

Actually, Application Gateway supports web-based traffic load balancing. [Azure load balancer][2] supports stream-based traffic. If you want to listen to the protocol HTTP or HTTPS, you can use Application Gateway. Per your description, you could not access HPC management interface from web explorer, you could use a 4 layer load balancing based on TCP/UDP.

So you could create a public-facing load balancing and add the head node VMs as the backend pools. Create a health probe and load balancing rules to specify the ports you want to listen for your HPC management interface on the each of VMs.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any concerns.